# Undefined method `call' when try to call inheritance class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I've got a base class with `self.call` method:

```
module Jira
  class Base
    def self.call
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(required_fields)
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Jira::JiraConnection.new.call
    end

    def required_fields; end
  end
end
```

Which should be called in below class:

```
module Jira
  module Support
    module AutoResolved
      class NewCollaborator < Jira::Base
        def required_fields
          {
            'fields' => {
              'summary' => 'Add <Github user> collaborator to <github_repo>',
              'description' => 'This is an automatic confirmation ticket'
              'project' => { 'key' => 'SUP' }
            }
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In rails console I tried `::Jira::Support::AutoResolved::NewCollaborator.new.call` but I'm getting an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for #<Jira::Support::AutoResolved::NewCollaborator:0x00007fbcc3b8abc8>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call method is inside the static class/singleton class/ghost class.
Remove the keyword self from def and it should work

```
module Jira
  class Base
    def call
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(required_fields)
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Jira::JiraConnection.new.call
    end

    def required_fields; end
  end
end
```